# Get full billing address in amazon mws reports

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, amazon-mws

I am using _GET_ORDERS_DATA_ report to pull orders to be fulfilled. But this report does not seem to give full billing address(it misses state,zip,city,country) unlike the shipping address. Is there any way that i can get these details for billing address?

Comment: There is no other way. This is the only way to get it. we are using shipping address as billing. In the document it mentioned about billing address but in get report it never provides. we are not verifying each order. i think if billing and shipping are different then they will mention or provide the report.

Comment: @Bck Have you been able to resolve this? There seem to be sellers wo do get a billing address and others who don't!?!

Comment: No. As of now I am assuming billing address to be same as shipping address.

Answer (score 1):

I do have billing and shipping addresses in this report type. You need to call Amazon's sellerservice and ask them to do so, that's what helped me out.

Billing data is provided in the BillingData Tag.

Here's a complete orderreport

```
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion><MerchantIdentifier>ddd</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderReport</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderReport>
<AmazonOrderID>ddd</AmazonOrderID>
<AmazonSessionID>ddd</AmazonSessionID>
<OrderDate>2014-07-27T08:13:14+00:00</OrderDate>
<OrderPostedDate>2014-07-27T08:13:14+00:00</OrderPostedDate>
<BillingData>
<BuyerEmailAddress>ddd</BuyerEmailAddress>
<BuyerName>ddd</BuyerName>
<BuyerPhoneNumber>ddd</BuyerPhoneNumber>
<Address>
<Name>ddd</Name>
<AddressFieldOne>ddd</AddressFieldOne>
<City>ddd</City>
<StateOrRegion>ddd</StateOrRegion>
<PostalCode>ddd</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>dd</CountryCode>
<PhoneNumber>dd</PhoneNumber>
</Address>
</BillingData>
<FulfillmentData>
<FulfillmentMethod>Ship</FulfillmentMethod><FulfillmentServiceLevel>Standard</FulfillmentServiceLevel>
<Address>
<Name>ddd</Name>
<AddressFieldOne>ddd</AddressFieldOne>
<City>ddd</City>
<StateOrRegion>ddd</StateOrRegion>
<PostalCode>ddd</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>ddd</CountryCode>
<PhoneNumber>ddd</PhoneNumber>
</Address>
</FulfillmentData>
<Item>
<AmazonOrderItemCode>ddd</AmazonOrderItemCode>
<SKU>1103112</SKU>
<Title>ddd</Title>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<ProductTaxCode>PTC_PRODUCT_TAXABLE_A</ProductTaxCode>
<ItemPrice>
<Component>
<Type>Principal</Type>
<Amount currency="EUR">412.67</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Type>Shipping</Type>
<Amount currency="EUR">12.95</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Type>Tax</Type>
<Amount currency="EUR">0.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Type>ShippingTax</Type>
<Amount currency="EUR">0.00</Amount>
</Component>
</ItemPrice>
<ItemFees>
<Fee>
<Type>Commission</Type>
<Amount currency="EUR">-29.79</Amount>
</Fee>
</ItemFees>
</Item>
</OrderReport>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: Yes. But the BllingData does not have zip,state,country etc, unlike the shipping address. A complete address with all these details is what I wanted.

Comment: Yes it does, did you see the response I posted?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem!
Theres still no **BillingData** in the response.
And I ask amazon to activate this and they do so.